# Matrix and two vectors product

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, notation, index-notation

Does anyone know how to represent the product of an $n×n$ matrix and two $n$-vectors in a compact form using $\sum$ and indexes?

If it was only a vector then $\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{i,j}v_j$. But with two vectors I have no clue.

Comment: Do you have any hunches as to the notation?

Comment: If it was only a vector then $\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{i,j}v_j$. But with two vectors I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the square matrix is $A$ with entries $a_{ij}$ (first index refers to the row, second to the column) and the two vectors are $p=(p_i)^T$ and $q=(q_i)^T$. Then
$$p^TAq=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^np_iA_{ij}q_j=\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}p_iA_{ij}q_j$$

Comment: How do you know if $p=(p_i)^T$ and $q=(q_i)^T$ are the vector represented as a row or a column?

Comment: @roy212 When vectors are given like $(p_i)^T$ they are assumed as column vectors. $(p_i)$ is then a row vector.

Comment: I try to understand it with one example.Let the matrix be $ \begin{pmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
4 &2 
\end{pmatrix}$ If I understood it rigthly  $p_i=(3,4)$(row vector) and $q_j=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}$ column vector. Can I multiply the three components  $p_i A_{i,j}q_j$ at the same
time, here for "i=1", "j=1", the first component of the final result would be $3$x$2$x$1$ =6? Or should I multiply first the vector $p_i$ with the matrix $A_{i,j}$ and the result with $q_j$? Is this correct? When you only have a matrix and one vector the order is not a problem.

Comment: @roy212 **Matrix multiplication is associative.** As long as you do not change the order of the matrices themselves, the result is still the same.

Comment: Here we have three "matrices". Can you multiply the three at the same time? Or only two each time?

Comment: @roy212 Only two at once, but the result is the same no matter if the left one or right one is done first.

Comment: I understand,now,  that the product is associative.I'm trying to read the index notation. In your answer, the inner summation starts with the letter j. I think that when you have two summations, first you use the inner one and then the outter one. Does this imply that in your answer you should first multiply the matrix $A$ with $q_j$ and the result of this product with "p_i"? And in no way first $p_i$ with $A$ and the result with "q_j"?

Comment: @roy212 As I said, either way works. This is what I mean with the second two-index summation.

Comment: Thanks. This is all new to me. One last doubt I have.
If $n=3$,

$p=(p_i)^T$ that means that $p=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}$

$q=(q_i)^T$ that means that $q=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}$


On the LHS of your notation, $p^TAq$, $p^T$ is then $=\begin{pmatrix}
a &b  & c
\end{pmatrix}$ a row vector. I didn't understand that after the summations you wrote $p_i$. If "i" is an index meant for rows then there is only one row and not three. You only run the vector once,for i=1. For i=2 and i=3, there's no row two and row three.

Comment: The same for $q_j$ after the summations. "j" is meant for columns and $q=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}$ has only one column instead of three.

Comment: @roy212 but it doesn't matter, since $p,q$ are both one dimension. I take the indices to refer to the values going either right or down, depending on whether it is a row or column vector respectively.

Answer (score 0):

What about 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij} (u_j,v_j)$$
for two vectors ,$u$ and $v$

It could be generalized to more vectors.

Comment: is $(u_j,v_j)$ the dot product?

Comment: No , it is an ordered pair.

Comment: I don't quite understand it. With the distributive property, isn't it $\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}u_j  \sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}v_j?$

Comment: Yes it is just  $(\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}u_j , \sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}v_j)$ in a compact form.